# Unable to find stylesheets in multiples nativescript styleurls

Tags: css, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using `nativescript-angular 1.2.0` and `tns-core-modules 2.5.0`.

Here my login.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "myapp",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.common.css", "./login-component.android.css"]
})
```

But while compiling it is unable to find `login-component.android.css`.

I've already remove, build, add etc.

I change the second css file multiple times, but there is a Bug, nativescript is unable to find the second stylesheet.

Comment: Are you sure, if the path to the CSS file that doesn't get loaded is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change `login-component.android.css` to `login-component.css` as that '.android' bit is resolved automatically on Android builds.

Also, since you're using `module: module.id` you can drop the `./` so it becomes: `styleUrls: ["login.common.css", "login-component.css"]`

And make sure the file is `login-component`, not `login.component`, etc.

Comment: But why in the "Grocery" on github, they used login.component.android.css ??

Comment: No they don't: https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/master/app/login/login.component.ts#L16